# C# must declare a body error with InfoPath button to run PowerShell script

Tags: c#, powershell, infopath

I'm trying to launch a PowerShell script from an InfoPath (2013) form button. I'm new to C#. I'm getting the following error message -

"'SP_checklist_v1_8.FormCode.CTRL171_5_Clicked(object, Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.ClickedEventArgs)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"

Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

I've set it to use framework 4.5 and referenced System.Management.Automation.

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace SP_checklist_v1_8
{
    public partial class FormCode
    {
        // Member variables are not supported in browser-enabled forms.
        // Instead, write and read these values from the FormState
        // dictionary using code such as the following:
        //
        // private object _memberVariable
        // {
        //     get
        //     {
        //         return FormState["_memberVariable"];
        //     }
        //     set
        //     {
        //         FormState["_memberVariable"] = value;
        //     }
        // }

        // NOTE: The following procedure is required by Microsoft InfoPath.
        // It can be modified using Microsoft InfoPath.
        public void InternalStartup()
        {
            ((ButtonEvent)EventManager.ControlEvents["CTRL171_5"]).Clicked += new ClickedEventHandler(CTRL171_5_Clicked);
        }

        public void CTRL171_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e);
            // Write your code here.

                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {            
                        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault());
                        runspace.Open();

                        PowerShell powerShellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
                        powerShellCommand.Runspace = runspace;
                        powerShellCommand.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");            
                        powerShellCommand.AddScript("C:\\Users\\John.Doe\\PowerShellscripts\\SmokeTest.ps1").Invoke();
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                        runspace.Close();
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Expected result - Opens and runs a PowerShell script.

Comment: `public void CTRL171_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)` is followed by a `;` when it should be `{ }` for an empty method.

Comment: That was it. Thanks.